# Alarm for firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have created an alarm system to be used by caregiver to set alarms for the elderly. In this alarm, how do i get the latest alarm that has been set to be placed on top, instead of just appearing at the bottom every single time

```
mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<notify>(this, notify.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mRoot) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, notify notify, int i) {
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(notify.getCourse() + "Quantity:" + notify.getQuantity() +"," + notify.getRepeat());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText("Medication set to " +notify.getDate() + " at " + notify.getTime());
        }
    }; listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that by default children are retrieved in ascending order of their keys. If in your case keys are generated automatically by Firebase (for example using `push()` function), then their values are based on the timestamp, and a key generated later is greater than any key generated before. Thus the last alarm you created appears at the bottom of the list.

In order to reverse this order, you can for each child object store the value `0 - timestamp` under its property called `created_timestamp`, where `timestamp` is the timestamp when the object was created. Then, you can use function `orderBy('created timestamp')` to retrieve children with the intended order.

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the data is not a problem for the `FirebaseListAdapter` to solve. Instead you can either solve it in your database query (`mRoot`) or in your Android view. A [whole book worth of questions on reversing a query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+reverse) has been answered in the past, so I'll focus on reversing the items in the view here.

Since you're using a `ListView`:

```
listView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

For a `RecyclerView` the equivalent would be:

```
manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: i have added the listView.setStackFromBottom(true), but it still does not rearrange my data to display the latest on top. Why is that so?